# convert oracle query output to xlsx ( excel ) format in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I have the query like

select * from table ;

I want to put that result into xlsx format and schedule that query.
I have the issue in how to load oracle query result into xlsx ?

Comment: Use `SQL Developer` and export the results in `xlsx` format.

Comment: Use spool to output query result into .csv file.

Comment: but i want to schedule that query rsult and directly mail to respective user.

but is there any way to get .xlsx file directly

Comment: You should consider using Java for this. Check out Apache POI (https://poi.apache.org/) for generating the xlsx file and Apache Mail (https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-email/) for sending mail.

Answer (score 0):

Use Spool to export the query result into csv:

```
set colsep ,     -- separate columns with a comma
set pagesize 0   -- No header rows
set trimspool on -- remove trailing blanks
set headsep off  -- this may or may not be useful...depends on your headings.
set linesize X   -- X should be the sum of the column widths
set numw X       -- X should be the length you want for numbers (avoid scientific notation on IDs)

spool myfile.csv

select * from TABLE;
```

A true xlsx file is a binary file in a MS proprietary format.

sqlplus can only return character strings -- text data.  'spool' only writes what sqlplus returns -- character strings.

Comment: error =>   line 1: File C:\Program Files\Quest Software\SQL Navigator for Oracle 7.1\export on.sql not found

Comment: i have edited my answer ..please try it...you can edit the set options accordingly you want

Comment: its working for me ..may be try to give correct path

Comment: where are you trying to run the sql query using spool ?

Comment: now query run and file generated in particular location but when i open this .xlsx file gives error like ( error=> excel can not open the file 'myfile.xlsx' because the file format or file extension is not valid.

Comment: ok can you change query to spool myfile.csv and then try to run the query again and open the file..

Comment: Now gives error like file name not exist when i enter query like 

spool D:\myfile.csv

Comment: just try to spool myfile.csv instead of D:\myfile.csv

Comment: gives error like =>

[1]:(Error): Filename: C:\Program Files\Quest Software\SQL Navigator for Oracle 7.1\myfile.csv is not exist.

Comment: where are you running this query ? i mean which tool you are using ?

Comment: In SQL navigator 7.1.0
SQL Navigator for Oracle 7.1

Comment: i didnt use SQL Navigator before but if you select the complete query and dont press Run Statement instead press Run Script then only it works in sql developer